# How to append to a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary of dictionaries like this:

```
food = {"Broccoli": {"Taste": "Bad", "Smell": "Bad"},
        "Strawberry": {"Taste": "Good", "Smell": "Good"}}
```

But I am populating it from an SQL table. So I've pulled the SQL table into an SQL object called "result". And then I got the column names like this:

```
nutCol = [i[0] for i in result.description]
```

The table has about 40 characteristics, so it is quite long.

I can do this...

```
foodList = {}
for id, food in enumerate(result):
    addMe = {str(food[1]): {nutCol[id + 2]: food[2], nulCol[idx + 3]: 
            food[3] ...}}
    foodList.update(addMe)
```

But this of course would look horrible and take a while to write. And I'm still working out how I want to build this whole thing so it's possible I'll need to change it a few times...which could get extremely tedious.

Is there a DRY way of doing this?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression

Comment: See that doesn't quite work for me because it's a dictionary of dictionaries. It's not just adding one key/pair at a time. I need to be able to say something like foodList["Chicken"]["Protein"]

Comment: Your suggested code is not making a dictionary of dictionaries ... is there a particular field you think of as the "id" that you want to associate the other properties with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that column 0 is what you wish to use as your key, and you do wish to build a dictionary of dictionaries, then its:

```
detail_names = [col[0] for col in result.description[1:]]
foodList = {row[0]: dict(zip(detail_names, row[1:]))
            for row in result}
```

Generalising, if column `k` is your identity then its:

```
foodList = {row[k]: {col[0]: row[i]
                     for i, col in enumerate(result.description) if i != k}
            for row in result}
```

(Here each sub dictionary is all columns other than column `k`)

Answer (score 2):

In order to make solution position independent you can make use of `dict1.update(dict2)`. This simply merges dict2 with dict1.

In our case since we have dict of dict, we can use `dict['key']` as dict1 and simply add any additional key,value pair as dict2.

Here is an example.

```
food = {"Broccoli": {"Taste": "Bad", "Smell": "Bad"}, 
        "Strawberry": {"Taste": "Good", "Smell": "Good"}}

addthis = {'foo':'bar'}
```

Suppose you want to add `addthis` dict to `food['strawberry']` , we can simply use,

```
food["Strawberry"].update(addthis)
```

Getting result:

```
>>> food
{'Strawberry': {'Taste': 'Good', 'foo': 'bar', 'Smell': 'Good'},'Broccoli': {'Taste': 'Bad', 'Smell': 'Bad'}}
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

`addMe = {str(food[1]):dict(zip(nutCol[2:],food[2:]))}`

`zip` will take two (or more) lists of items and pair the elements, then you can pass the result to `dict` to turn the pairs into a dictionary.