# how to safely append to a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I know there's a similar question:

[How to append to a dictionary of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43671312/how-to-append-to-a-dictionary-of-dictionaries)

but the answers aren't working for me. My problem is as follows. If I need to add a new `key: value` pair to a Python dictionary, then

```
my_dict[key] = value
```

is always safe (as long as `key` is not a mutable type), whether `my_dict` had been already initialized or not.

*However*, if I want `my_dict` to be a dictionary of dictionaries, then

```
my_dict[keyA][keyB] = value
```

**doesn't work**, unless I already initialized `my_dict[keyA]` as an empty dictionary. So what I'm doing right now is:

```
class dict_of_dict():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ddict = {}
    
    def update(self, keyA, keyB, value):
        if not(keyA in self.ddict.keys()):
            self.ddict[keyA] = {}
        self.ddict[keyA][keyB] = value

a = dict_of_dict()
a.update(0, 3, "foobar")

a.ddict
```

This works, but I feel like it's overkill. Is there a more compact/Pythonic **but still readable** solution?

Comment: `from collections import defaultdict; a = defaultdict(dict)`

Comment: `my_dict.setdefault(keyA, {})[keyB] = value`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tested your solution, it works and it's readable! If you post it as answer I'll gladly accept it.